# How can I do partial indexing on Pandas MultiIndexed DataFrame?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown. For now, I want to look at the rows with 'match' == 1.
I am not sure how do I go about it.

The ultimate goal is to get rid of those rows that do not correspond to a date (could be represented by either match ==0 or match ==1)

```
>>> df.to_dict()
  {(1, 0): '09/14/20',
  (1, 1): '90792',
  (2, 0): '5/18/71',
  (3, 0): '8/09/19',
  (4, 0): '6/05/93',
  (4, 1): '90791',
  (5, 0): '8/9/97',
  (6, 0): '12/8/82',
  (7, 0): '8/26/89',
  (7, 1): '90791',
  (8, 0): '10/13/95',
  (8, 1): '90791',
  (9, 0): '4/19/91',
  (10, 0): '04/08/20',
  (10, 1): '04 16',
  (11, 0): '9/20/76',
  (11, 1): '90801',
  (12, 0): '12/08/19'}
```

PS: I have a text file and I had to extract date from each line of the file. So what I did was this:

```
import pandas as pd
doc = []
with open('dates.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        doc.append(line)
    df = pd.Series(doc)

    df = df.str.extractall(r'(?P<Date>(([0123]?\d)|([ADFJMNOS][aceopu][a-z] 
         {1,}))[\s,/-]?(([0123]?\d)|([ADFJMNOS][aceopu][a-z]{1,}))[\s,/-]?(? 
         P<Year>(\d{2}|\d{4})))')
    df.index.rename(['Id','Match'],inplace=True)
```

I am not sure if that's the most efficient way to extract dates (present in various formats) and wrapped within English sentences, so it will be appreciated if  someone can comment on my code's efficiency and brevity so far.
Date formats in the text file are as:

```
04/20/2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09
Mar-20-2009; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009;
20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009
Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009
Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010
6/2008; 12/2009
2009; 2010
```

Comment: Hi Ash, you'll find that you'll get more answers if you can show how you've already tried to deal with the problem (and if you post your example as code rather than an image).

Comment: @ASGM Thanks for the advice. But it comes from a large text file, so I am not sure if I could bring the whole file here. Plus, I have been trying df.loc['match'], df.loc[(None,'match')] they all throw an error that 'match' is not in the index. I have tried reading the Python documentation on MultiIndexing, but it doesn't help much.

Comment: @Ash post your `df.to_dict()` instead of an image

Comment: @RafaelC I posted the glimpse of df.to_dict() if that helps! Thanks!

Comment: @Ash the dict you provided does not yield the data frame you had in the image !

Comment: @RafaelC I removed the image and posted the above dict as data to work on, the image that I posted earlier is still a part of this data, just a different segment. But, did you get the whole picture of what I am trying to do here? Thanks and sorry for all the hassle!

Comment: @Ash Not sure if this is what you want. But try: `df[df.index.get_level_values(1) == 0]`

Comment: @RafaelC Thanks, that helps! Also, do you think the Regex expression that I used is efficient? Can it be improved any further?

Comment: @Ash - if you need help with your date parsing, don't add it to this question - open a new question specifically about this.  In that question, make it clear what you want the answers to help with - "comment on the code" is likely to be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `match` is an index column, you use [index slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html) to get the values you want:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:,1], :]
```

Breaking down the `.loc` statement, the first argument is for the index and the second is for the columns.  Since you have two index columns, you can use a list of two items to select from each index column.  The first item, `:`, selects all the items in the first index column.  The second selects only those rows with a value of `1` in the second index column.

If `match` were a column, you could do the following:

```
df[df.match == 1]
```

If you make `df.match` a column of booleans (`True`/`False`), you can just do `df[df.match]`.

Comment: Hi @ASGM, df.match is throwing an error. I have updated the question with more details if you would like to look at it again. Thanks!

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear in the original version that `match` was an index column.  Updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, got it! Shouldn't it be df.loc[idx[:,1],:] ? Guess it;s just a typo.

Comment: @Ash, yes, good catch!  It should indeed be `df.loc[idx[:,1], :]`